# How to Fetch Data from Different dbs with same collection in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data

How to fetch data from two dbs and same collection?. Currently I'm using mongoDB

Example

first db is DB_A and collection name is userData. Second db is DB_B and collection name is userData.

I want to apply filter, sort and pagination. If I'll fetch data from both dbs and combine it. Then will not be sorted.
I want fetch data in single call from MongoDB site.

I tried couple of way to resolve this. I fetched data from both dbs then applying in-memory sorting, pagination

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like a sharded Database, you should probably have setup a sharded Cluster.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/

If you don't wanna do that you could add a level of abstraction on your datasource, i don't know what client you are using but you probably wanna override your query method to query both databases and then merge the result set in case of a sharded Collection. And yes the filtering and sorting would have to be done in memory.